# Feature Request: New Website

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal

How about starting a website for designers i.e questions relating photoshop and illustrator?
Would really help people like me a lot

Comment: You should have a look at Area51.Stackexchange.com, it dedicated to proposing new sites. But this doesn't belong here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a proposal for [Graphic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) that is nearing full commitment on Area 51.

Comment: Yes! Please commit to this. When it reaches 100% commitment, it will go into a working beta. It is quite close to this now.

Answer (score 1):

The [Graphic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) proposal mentioned by moberly was followed through to completion. The site can be visited now [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)!